# What does *.hlsl files do, what the relationship between this file and *.fx file?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I am reading an example of DirectX project, I saw `*.fx` and `*.hlsl` files.

I know `fx` is effect file which is read by DirectX, but what's purpose of `hlsl` file? Are this files useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically `fx` contains shaders using the Effects system syntax (`technique`, `pass`, etc.) while `hlsl` contains pure HLSL shaders without Effects system syntax.

This is, however, purely a convention and one that is not actually followed particularly consistently. In the end, all that matters is what profile you use to compile the file with. VS 2012+ will treat either `fx` or `hlsl` files the same (i.e. as something you build with FXC).

The latest Effects for Direct3D 11 is available on [CodePlex](https://fx11.codeplex.com/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11), but the complier support for the `fx_5_0` profile is officially deprecated. It still works, but it has a number of known issues and will likely be removed at some point in the future.

See this discussion thread on the Effects 11 projects site: [What's the difference between an .fx and .hlsl file anyhow?](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/551307)

Answer (score 0):

.hlsl files contain shaders and their includes. .fx effect system is deprecated and not included in DirectX SDK anymore.

Comment: The DirectX SDK itself is deprecated. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx).